# Angular 4 + Md2 tabs: Set a tab to be active on coming back to page

Tags: angular, tabs, md2

My app is in Angular 4 and using [Md2 module for the tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md2-tabs). What I’m trying to achieve is basically to set the active tab to be **Shopping list** tab instead of the default **Design brief** tab ONLY when user comes back from *Product* page. The detailed flow description is in the picture below.

[flow illustrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtOZz.png)

Here's the code:

***project-details.component.html:***

```
<md2-tabs [selectedIndex]=”activeTabIndex”>
    <md2-tab label=”Design Brief”></md2-tab>
    <md2-tab label=”Shopping List”></md2-tab>
</md2-tabs>
```

***project-details.component.ts:***

```
export class ProjectDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    activeTabIndex: number = 0;

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events
            .filter((e: any) => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe((e: any) => {
                this.activeTabIndex = e[0].urlAfterRedirects.startsWith("/product")
                    ? 1
                    : 0;
            });
    }
}
```

***product.component.html:***

```
<button (click)="onCancel()"> X </button>
```

***product.component.ts:***

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private location: Location) {}

    onCancel() {
        this.location.back();
    }
}
```

My questions are (within the use of Angular 4/Md2 module, as we're not considering upgrading Angular version or implementing Material Angular at this point of time):

- How do I get the `selectedIndex` attribute on `<md2-tabs>` dynamically changed when `activeTabIndex` prop changes in the `subscribe` function? (currently the changes are happening in the `subscribe` function but it seems the `activeTabIndex` property is not updated.
- Are there any other possibilities that I should be looking at in order to get the user back to that **Shopping list** tab when they’re coming from a Product page?

Any help would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: In the subscribe block, after setting `this.activeTabIndex`, do `console.log(this.activeTabIndex)` to ensure it is set to 1 and not 0.

Comment: @AliF50 yeah it's set to 1 inside `subscribe` block, but outside after `subscribe` it logs `undefined` as subscribe is async. I'm a bit new to angular so I'm not sure if there is a way to get around this?

Comment: You're right, the subscribe is async. That behaviour you mentioned is normal. The package you are using is `alpha` and only one release. I tried installing it on version 4 of Angular on StackBlitz but I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
 <md2-tabs>
    <md2-tab [active]="designActive" label=”Design Brief”></md2-tab>
    <md2-tab [active]="listActive" label=”Shopping List”></md2-tab>
</md2-tabs>
```

```
designActive = false;
listActive = false;

ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events
            .filter((e: any) => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe((e: any) => {
                this.activeTabIndex = e[0].urlAfterRedirects.startsWith("/product")
                    if (e[0].urlAfterRedirects.startsWith('/products')) {
                     this.listActive = true;
                   } else {
                      this.designActive = true; 
                   }
            });
    }
```

Put a `console.log` in the `if` and `else` and see which section it falls into.

Comment: thanks, those console logs work as expected, but still they're not changing the values outside of `subscribe`, so the `active` attribute is not really getting any update :(

Comment: Seeing that there was only one release of this `npm package` and it being an alpha, it could have issues. Maybe compromise and come up with your own tabs.